# Error on Result

Tags: c

```
int idade, salario,maior, menor, media, somasalario =0, i=0; 
char sexo; 
char estadoc;

do { 

   printf("Insira a sua idade:");
   scanf("%d", &idade);
    if (idade > maior) {
        maior = idade;
    }
    if (idade < menor) {
        menor = idade;
    }

   printf("Insira o seu salario:");
   scanf("%d", &salario);
   somasalario += salario;


       printf("Introduza o seu sexo:");
       scanf("%c", &sexo);
       printf("Introduza o seu estado civil:");
       scanf("%c", &estadoc);

       printf("Salario menor que 0!");


}while(idade !=-1); 

printf("idade maior: %d", maior);
```

}

it's my code, and when i run the program, the printf stay like this:

"Insira o seu salario:500
Introduza o seu sexo:Introduza o seu estado civil:
"

someone can help me please?

Comment: `if (idade > maior)` and `if (idade < menor)` are **undefined behaviour** due to uninitialised variables. Not checking return value from `scanf()`. All very basic errors.

Comment: `scanf("%c", &sexo);` and `scanf("%c", &estadoc);` - not cleaning off previous whitespace in input buffer.

Comment: thanks, my head is not well! 10 hours of progamming ...

Answer (score 1):

I have annotated various corrections to your program. It now works, although it does not seem to do anything very useful. In fact it always tells me *"Salario menor que 0!"*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>                                 // added header

int main(void)
{
    int idade=0, salario=0, maior=INT_MIN, menor=INT_MAX, somasalario=0; 
    char sexo=' ', estadoc=' ';                     // initialised variables

    do { 
        printf("Insira a sua idade: ");
        if (scanf("%d", &idade) != 1)
            return 1;                               // input error
        if (idade > maior) {
            maior = idade;
        }
        if (idade < menor) {
            menor = idade;
        }

        printf("Insira o seu salario: ");
        if (scanf("%d", &salario) != 1)
            return 1;                               // input error
        somasalario += salario;

        printf("Introduza o seu sexo: ");
        if (scanf(" %c", &sexo) != 1)               // added space to clean input
            return 1;                               // input error
        printf("Introduza o seu estado civil: ");
        if (scanf(" %c", &estadoc) != 1)            // added space to clean input
            return 1;                               // input error

        printf("Salario menor que 0!\n");           // added newline
    } while(idade !=-1); 

    printf("idade maior: %d\n", maior);             // added newline
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: the "salario menor que 0" is a line that i forgot to delete... but thanks for the help! my head is not well today...